# How can i make a 2 dimensional array out of 2 1 dimensional arrays in Swift 2

Tags: swift, sorting, multidimensional-array

I know that I need to move away from Swift 2, but I am 95% and thought I'd finish before converting.

I'm working on a music player.  I have a 1 dimensional array of persistentIDs (UInt64) which I store and read in later.  I can use each one to find their corresponding albumTitle's and store those in a 1 dimensional array (String).  My goal is to combine them, in order, and then to sort them by the albumTitle's.  After that I want to extract the persistentID's which are now in a different order.

```
var array1: [UInt64] = [UInt64]()    // Ex: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var array2: [String] = [String]()    // Ex: [d, a, e, b, c]
var array2D:[(UInt64, String)] = []

// Unsorted 2D array ex: [[1,d], [2,a], [3,e], [4,b], [5,c]]

// Sorted 2D array ex: [[2,a], [4,b], [5,c], [1,d], [3,e]]

// Final 1D array ex: [2, 4, 5, 1, 3]
```

I can't create the unsorted 2D array.  I found the following code on this site and thought I could try to adapt it, but kept getting the error: Expected '{' to start the body of for-each loop

```
var N: Int
var array: [[Int]] = []
for row in 0..<N {
    // Append an empty row.
    array.append([Int]())

    for _ in 0..<N {
        // Populate the row.
        array[row].append(Int(arc4random_uniform(100)))
    }
}
```

I've spent the better part of a day trying to figure this out.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Is the `zip` function available in your version of Swift? I think it is available in Swift 2.2 at least (not sure), and I think it's what you want to use to combine two arrays into a single array of tuples.

Comment: https://youtu.be/_S6UOrwS-Tg?t=7m12s

Comment: Yes, the zip function is available.  Xcode 7.3.1.  I have to learn about tuples.  Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creating 2D array

```
    let array1: [UInt64] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    let array2: [String] = ["d", "a", "e", "b", "c"]

    var array2D = Array(zip(array1, array2))

    print(array2D); // [(1,"d"), (2,"a"), (3,"e"), (4,"b"), (5,"c")]
```

sorting method

```
    array2D.sort { $0.1 < $1.1 }

    print(array2D); // [(2, "a"), (4, "b"), (5, "c"), (1, "d"), (3, "e")]
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  This worked!  I had to make a small change to the sort line:  let sorted2DArray = array2D.sort { $0.1 < $1.1 }.  Then, in order to extract the list of sorted IDs, I used: let sorted1DarrayOfIDs = sorted2DarrayOfIDsAndTitles.map { tuple in tuple.0 }  I know this may not be the most efficient way of doing things.  Funny thing is, I could have written this 2D array stuff in old-school C in about 10 mins.  I have much to learn.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the "unsorted array":

```
var array1: [UInt64] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var array2: [String] = ["d", "a", "e", "b", "c"]

var array2D = Array(zip(array1, array2))  // [(1,"d"), (2,"a"), (3,"e"), (4,"b"), (5,"c")]
```

Not that this is not a 2-D array. It's still a 1-D array of 2-tuples.

What you meant by "sorted array" is not clear

Comment: A 1-D array of 2-tupples will get it done.  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

First. In Swift 2, arrays are much more efficient at storing things than dictionaries, thus limiting your options on performance balancing. Swift 3 made big improvements on this, narrowing the performance gap.
Because of this: As was pointed out in previous posts, your 2D array is nothing more than an array of two tuples. This poses the problem of: you'd have to check the type of each element of every 1D array in your 2D array, to know which value is the id and the title. Your 2D array can be simply made into an array of dictionaries/objects. Which is what you should be doing from the beginning: using a class which can track where things are, for easy manipulation. this avoids your issue of things getting mixed up, which can happen when storing locally and then retrieving later. Mind you, this works well for small to medium-sized lists, otherwise, you'll need better logic, or a different approach with larger lists. But, Something like this always work well to begin with:

```
class Track {

    var id : UInt64
    var title : String

    init(id: UInt64, title: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
    }
}

class Playlist {

    var name = String()

    var playlistId : UInt64?

    var tracks : [Track] = []

    private var indexes : [String:Int] = [:]

    private var idList : [UInt64:String] = [:]

    init(name: String, tracks: [Track]?) {
        self.name = name
        if let t = tracks {
            for track in t {
                addSongWithoutOrdering(track)
            }
            orderSongs()
        }
    }

    private func addSongWithoutOrdering(_ song: Track) {
        tracks.append(song)
    }

    func addSong(_ track: Track) {
        tracks.append(track)
        orderSongs()
        print("Added song titled: \(track.title) to playlist : \(name)")
    }

    func removeSongBy(_ id: UInt64) {
        if let title = idList[id], let index = indexes[title] {
            idList.removeValue(forKey: id)
            indexes.removeValue(forKey: title)
            tracks.remove(at: index)
            orderSongs()
        } else {
            print("No song with id: \(id) exists in playlist : \(name)")
        }
    }

    func removeSongBy(_ title: String) {
        if let index = indexes[title] {
            idList.removeValue(forKey: tracks[index].id)
            indexes.removeValue(forKey: title)
            tracks.remove(at: index)
            orderSongs()
        } else {
            print("Removed song with title: \(title) in playlist : \(name)")
        }
    }

    private func orderSongs () {
        tracks.sort { $0.title < $1.title }
        for (index, track) in tracks.enumerated() {
            indexes[track.title] = index
            idList[track.id] = track.title
        }
    }

}
```

By doing this, you can also sort out playlists, into groups of playlists and so on. You can also make some values optionals, if you dont have access to them right away (ie, they need to be fetched from an API).

Conlusion: Make the jump to Swift 3, or adopt a class like the one above!

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the help!  I am going to study your code in the sandbox.  It may turn out to be the best way to go.  There are just a couple more simple things I want to add, then I can save it, and convert to Swift 3 (and soon Swift 4).  Thank you very much.

Comment: I meant Playground not Sandbox.

Comment: No worries, hope it works out! Upvote if it ends up being helpful!